# Module 'xxx' is imported from Maven. Any changes made in its configuration may be lost after reimporting

Tags: maven, java-8

⭐I have met the following problem several times, and dealt with it over and over...

[image]

⭐Until today, I found out where the problem is, but can't solve it~

`Module 'xxx' is imported from Maven. Any changes made in its configuration may be lost after reimporting`

[image]

⭐**As the picture shows, once I reimport All Maven projects, its version will change to 13 from 8...**

[image]

⭐After reimporting, it comes back:

[image]

I would appreciate it very grateful if you can assist me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following codes in the **pom.xml** of your project:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ensure jdk 1.8-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

configure both `<source>` and `<target>` to 1.8（it's up to you）.

reason: you have never set the jdk version. so every time you modify the *pom.xml* and reimport the dependencies, it will revert to the default JDK 13.